# Save and restore check status of multiple checkboxes in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, checkbox, google-chrome-extension

I can save and restore a user input in a text field, based on the ID of the field - the code works as i expect, like:

```
function save_options() {
  var api = document.getElementById('text_field').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
    savedApi: api,
    });
}    
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save_options);

function restore_options() {  
    chrome.storage.sync.get({"savedApi": ''}, function(items) {
      document.getElementById('text_field').value = items.savedApi;
    });
    }
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
```

Now i want to save the check status of multiple checkboxes. Should i really repeat this construction for every checkbox? Could somebody point me to a smarter way to save status of multiple checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

IF this inputs are in side a form you can use this method to get all form data

First way (It is 2019 and there's a better way to do this):

```
const form = document.querySelector('form'):
const data = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form).entries());
```

Second way (or if you want a plain Object instead):

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to use `URLSearchParams`.  Chrome storage can hold objects just fine, without any serialization.

Comment: oh thank you for the remark so we can use objects directly, that cool thanks.